# Remote Registry Query Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to make a powershell script that gets computer names from a txt file, checks the registry to see what the current version of Flash is installed, and if it is less than 18.0.0.203, run an uninstall exe. Here is what I have been trying:

```
# Retrieve computer names
$Computers = Get-Content C:\Users\araff\Desktop\FlashUpdater\Servers.txt

# Select only the name from the output
#$Computers = $Computers | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

#Sets command to execute if the version is not 18.0.0.203
$command = @'
cmd.exe /C uninstall_flash_player.exe -uninstall
'@

#Iterate through each computer and execute the command if the version is not 18.0.0.203
[Array]$Collection = foreach ($Computer in $Computers){

$AD = Get-ADComputer $computer -Properties LastLogonDate
$ping = Test-Connection -quiet -computername $computer -Count 2
$datetime = Get-Date

$Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computer)
$RegKey= $Reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayerActiveX")
$version = $RegKey.GetValue("Version")

if ($version -eq '= 18.0.0.203') {
        $installed = "Flash is up to date!"
    }
    Else {
        $installed = "Removing old version..."
        Invoke-Expression -Command:$command
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    TimeStamp = $datetime
    ComputerName = $computer
    Installed = $installed
    OnlineStatus = $ping
    LastLogonDate = $AD.LastLogonDate
} | Select-Object TimeStamp, ComputerName, Installed, OnlineStatus, LastLogonDate

}

#Exports csv
$Collection | Export-Csv FlashUpdaterOutput.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

It exports the CSV just fine, but all the installed columns say "Removing" even if it is the current version. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me that the '=' sign in the `if ($version -eq '= 18.0.0.203') {` line is what's wrong. Try changing it to `if ($version -eq '18.0.0.203') {`.

Comment: right after `$version = $RegKey.GetValue("Version")` put in `Return $Version`.  What's the value of the $Version variable?  Also pipe it to get-member and report on it's data type.

Comment: @AlexanderObersht, I put that there because when I was printing out $version to see what the value was, it was saying that the value of $version was "= 18.0.0.203" so I just put that in to see if it worked. I removed it and it appeared to do what it was supposed to do. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than opening a remote registry key and running cmd /c why not make a [scriptblock] and pipe it to Invoke-Command.

AsJob it and come back for the results later.

```
[scriptblock]$code = {
$uninst = gci "C:\Windows\System32\Macromed\Flash" -Filter "*.exe" | ?{ $_.Name -ne "FlashUtil64_18_0_0_204_ActiveX.exe" -and $_.Name -like "FlashUtil64_18_0_0_*_ActiveX.exe" }
foreach($flash in $uninst) {
    Write-Host $flash.FullName
    $proc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $proc.StartInfo.FileName = $flash.FullName
    $proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-uninstall"
    $proc.Start()
    $proc.WaitForExit()
    Write-Host ("Uninstalling {0} from {1}" -f $flash.BaseName,$env:COMPUTERNAME)
}
}

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $code -ComputerName frmxncsge01 -AsJob
```

Then later just come back and Get-Job | Receive-Job -Keep and see the results.